# Show that a transcendental simple extension has infinitely many intermediate fields.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Show that a transcendental simple extension has infinitely many intermediate fields.

I've been working on this for awhile but can't figure it out. Help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: How about $F(x)\supset F(x^p)$ for $p$ runs all prime number in $\Bbb Z$?

Comment: I think it works also. Or just natural numbers. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Let $F$ be the base field, and $K = F(\alpha)$ the simple transcendental extension. Are the intermediate subfields $F(\alpha^{2}), F(\alpha^{3}), \ldots$ distinct? Why?

Comment: That's my thought also. I think they are distinct since we can represent the elements  in $F(\alpha^n)$ as $b_0+b_1\alpha^n+b_2\alpha^{2n}+...$. Thus $F(\alpha^n) \subseteq F(\alpha^{n-1})\subseteq ...\subseteq F(\alpha)$.

Answer (score 0):

For field $F$ and $K=F(t)$, a simple transcendental extension, take polynomial expressions of degree $n$ in $t$ with coefficients in $F$, for example $t^n+1$.
Look at he subfields of $K$ generated by each of them.